# Expressing a function in terms of another

Tags: functional-analysis

I know this is a very nonsense question. But, it has become challenging for me to visualize. I have two functions as seen following:

$$\rho=\sum_{j\in J}\frac{\lambda_j}{\mu_j}$$
and
$$\theta=\sum_{j\in J}\frac{\lambda_j}{\mu_j^2}$$

Is there any way to express $\theta$ in terms of $\rho$ or vice versa?

Comment: I would say, "No."  How would you express $\frac1a+\frac1b$ in terms of $\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}?$

Comment: I also said, "No" and that's why I wanted to get more opinions. On the other hand, it seems, I can write $\theta = \sum_{j\in J}\frac{\lambda_j}{\mu_j}\frac{1}{\mu_j} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{\mu_j}\sum_{j\in J}\frac{\lambda_j}{\mu_j}$. Then, what is gonna happen with $\frac{1}{\mu_j}$?

Comment: You can't pull $1/u_j$ out of the summation sign.  Its value is different in every term of the sum.

Comment: @saulspatz, I am well aware of that. Just trying to put here something to get help if there is any possible way of doing that.

Comment: My best attempt:
$$\theta= - \sum_{j \in J} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_j} \rho$$
but it's really not easier than just writing
$$\theta = \sum_{j \in J} \frac{\lambda_j}{\mu_j^2}.$$